# Why is my mat-form-field not showing the label?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using angular material to construct a page, i'm trying to use the mat-form-field component but the label is not working and i don't know why. Can somebody help me, since now thank you all.

app.module.ts:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SignInComponent } from './views/sign-in/sign-in.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MatFormFieldModule } from "@angular/material/form-field";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SignInComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

sign-in.component.ts:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in',
  templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.css']
})
export class SignInComponent {

}
```

sign-in.component.html:

```html
<form>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Login</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text">
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: can you share code on stackblitz

Comment: i never used stackblitz but the repository on github is public, if i sent you the link would be usefull?

Comment: yes it will be more useful, and which version of angular are you using

Comment: the latest. github link: https://github.com/JhosefMatheus/ufrn-frontend

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem, the problem was that to mat-form-field show the label, it has to import MatInputModule, since now thank every one who'd helped me.

Answer (score 0):

you have to bind your template with your ts... add the formControl or form ControleName. You have to instantiate them in your class SignInComponent too